# Start function logic by datetime trigger python

Tags: python, datetime

I have the following function that checks if to run/stop another logic by datetime trigger:

```py
START_DATE = datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 7,16 ,30)
STOP_TIME = datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 8,4 ,30)]


def date_logic():

    if datetime.datetime.now() >= STOP_DATE:
        stop_all()

    if datetime.datetime.now() >= START_DATE:
        validate_before_start_all()
```

*`validate_before_start_all()` validates if the logic already run.

I want to "upgrade" my `date_logic()` function to run in multiple datetimes logic but not sure how to do that, i.e:

```py
date_times =[[datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 8,00 ,30), datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 8,4 ,30)],
                [datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 9,00 ,30), datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 9,4 ,30)]]

def date_logic():
    for date_time in date_times:
        start_date = date_time[0]
        stop_date = date_time[1]

        if datetime.datetime.now() >= stop_date:
            stop_all()

        if datetime.datetime.now() >= start_date:
            validate_before_start_all()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you want to check each datetime in `date_times` list if it is `>= stop_date` or  `>= start_date` ?